# Python performance drastically decrease after Anaconda and python reinstallatin

Tags: python, package, anaconda

Last week I have downloaded and installed from terminal the following package

https://pypi.org/project/pytket-quantinuum/

After that, any time I was running a python jupiter lab notebook ( simulation that I was doing also before), the kernel crashed while importing pytorch package. I had delated the other package, python and conda and then now torch packages are working again, but the computer has issue to do the simulations. As example, the same simulation that before have taken 2 min without problems, now it take the same time, but the computer slows down (if I'm listening music in the while, I hear the music fragmented!) but the notebook doesn't stop. For bigger simulations (that before I have done) the computer directly crash now ....

I tried to uninstall everything several times but nothing change. I also tried to run the code on visual Studio, but I have the same issue!

I have a Mac M1 with Big Sur. When I have reinstalled conda, there was a new version in the website.

Thanks for the answers and ask me if you need informations ! (it's my first post ever)